# question about Allah

Tags: salat, practical-islam, allah, imaan, life

I recently converted to Islam. I was born a Muslim but stopped being one for a few years, and now I am again. I’m praying again, reading the Quran sometimes, and trying my best not to sin. This might sound bad, but I don’t feel connected to Allah anymore like I did when I wanted to become a Muslim again. I feel sad and empty lately, maybe cause of things going on in my personal life but I’m not sure. Of course, I still want to be a Muslim but I don’t understand why I feel like this. Does this mean Allah isn’t listening to me or He doesn’t care?

Comment: The advice I'd give is to learn more about Allah. Reflect on His signs. The more you become aware of how powerful He is, the more you realise: you can ask Him for anything, you can rely on Him to help you, etc. He created the entire universe, of which we can barely even see any of it. Hope that helps. May Allah increase you in faith. May He increase you in beneficial knowledge.

Comment: No doubt that you are under the attack of Shaitan (Satan). Beware of Him. He has experience even with Prophets. Ordinary Muslims like you are a piece of cake for Him. Stay away from Haram. Establish your Salah and give Zakah. Make constant Zhikr of Allah. Ask Allah to strengthen your Iman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imaan (faith) increases and decreases all the time. Even the best of the worshippers sometimes become lethargic in terms of praying on time, controlling their tongues and limbs from sinning etc. Never give up. Increase listening to the Quran. Say plenty of Istiqfaar. Seek the company of friends who are connected to Mosque and seeking knowledge.

"Say; O my Servants who have transgressed against their souls! Despair not of the Mercy of Allah; for Allah forgives all sins; for He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful." -- Quran 39:53

Insha Allah that feeling will be replaced by joy and exerted effort to get closer to Allah.

"Those who believe, and whose hearts find satisfaction in the remembrance of Allah; for without doubt in the remembrance of Allah do hearts find satisfaction." -- Quran 13:28

"And those who strive in Our (cause),- We will certainly guide them to our Paths; For verily Allah is with those who do right." -- Quran 29:69